# Rails Action Cable: Authorize the incoming connection from mobile devices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

I want to authorize connection requests made to the **websocket connection via mobile devices**.
The code that I have in the `Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base` is as follows:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base

    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    private
      def find_verified_user
        if verified_user = User.find_by(id: cookies[:user_id])
          verified_user
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
      end
  end
end
```

This is working perfectly for the **WebBrowser Clients**, as I have set **cookies** as soon as the user signs in to the system using **Devise**.

That code looks something like this in the **SessionsController** from Devise:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    super
    cookies[:user_id] = current_user.id
  end
```

This is working fine.

But when I try to connect to the websocket connection via mobile, i get **reject_unauthorized_connection** error.

Also I tried setting cookies in the **`api/signin`** api, when the user signs in from the mobile. The **api code** looks something like this:

```
class Api::SessionsController < Api::ApiController

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email params[:email]

    if user && user.valid_password?(params[:password])

      # Set the user cookie
      cookies[:user_id] = user.id

      render json: { token: token_sign_in(user), user: user, department: user.department, organization: user.organization }
    else
      render json: { error: "invalid credentials" }, status: :unauthorized
    end
  end
```

Is the error happening because you can't set cookies on a mobile application ? If not, then what is the next best approach to authenticate the incoming websocket connection requests from mobile devices without using cookies.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to authenticate connection requests from a mobile device use **tokens** or a **unique identifiers(email id in my case)** that the mobile application sends to the server while logging in, with the header.

So, these are the changes that I made in my `connection.rb` file.

```
token = request.headers[:email]
  if token
    @verified_user = User.find_by(email: token)
  else
    reject_unauthorized_connection
  end
```

You could also use a **JWT token** instead of an email.